# Is every category a localization of a poset?

Tags: ct.category-theory, higher-category-theory

**Question 1:** Let $C$ be a small category. Does there exist a poset $P$, a set of $W$ of morphisms in $P$, and an equivalence $P[W^{-1}] \simeq C$?

Here $P[W^{-1}]$ is the universal category receiving a functor from $P$ which carries each morphism of $W$ to an isomorphism.

I'm hoping for an affirmative answer. I'm also interested in the following variation:

**Question 2:** Let $C$ be a small category with finite colimits. Does there exist a join-semilattice $P$, a set $W$ of morphisms in $P$, and an equivalence $P[W^{-1}] \simeq C$?

**Version control:**

- There are actually two versions of question 2 -- in one version we require that $P \to P[W^{-1}]$ preserves finite colimits, and in the other we don't. As I'm hoping for an affirmative answer, it should be *easier* to do this without requiring the preservation of the finite colimits, and I'd be happy with an answer to that version.
- On top of that, I am interested in two versions of these questions: the 1-categorical version and the $\infty$-categorical version (the term "poset" means the same thing in both versions).

**Other Notes:**

- I'm thinking a good way to try to construct such a $P$ in general may be via some sort of of subdivision of $C$. But I'm a bit unclear as to when the barycentric subdivision, say, of a category is a poset.

Comment: How would you get a monoid with no nonidentity isomorphisms but lots of noninvertible elements this way?

Comment: Like take the set of all selfmaps of the natural numbers and add an adjoined identity.  I don't see how you get this from inverting morphisms in a poset

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg Good question. Maybe even $B \mathbb N$ is problematic...

Comment: @TimCampion Isn't $B \mathbb{N}$ the localisation of $\{ 0 \to 1 \to 2 \}$ w.r.t. $\{ 0 \to 1, 0 \to 2 \}$?

Comment: @ZhenLin Hmmm.... If you localize at $0 \to 1$ and $0 \to 2$, then by 2/3 aren't you also localizing at $1 \to 2$, so that you get the terminal category?

Comment: You need something a bit bigger to get distinct parallel maps in the homotopy category. For example, there's a poset with four objects and four nonidentity maps whose geometric realization is a circle. Now invert three of those maps.

Comment: The first question is answered constructively in [Kerodon](https://kerodon.net/tag/02MC).

Comment: @MarcHoyois: That seems worth making an answer — it gives a much more self-contained presentation than [Chris’s answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/403122/2273).

Comment: @MarcHoyois Thanks! Do you happen to have studied Lurie's construction of $(P,W)$ closely enough to say whether it's _functorial_ in $C$?

Comment: So is the way you get a category equivalent to my favorite monoid is you use the inverted maps to make objects isomorphic rather than to create automorphisms and you create endomorphisms by forcing certain objects to get identified?

Comment: The variant of the construction given in the [exercise](https://kerodon.net/tag/02MV) is functorial in the simplicial set $S$, but it does not invert categorical equivalences.

Comment: As a noncategory theorist why does barycentric subdivision of simplicial sets realize categories as localizations?  Do you just replace a category by its nerve?

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg What these constructions do, more or less, is take a category, pass to the nerve, take the subdivision of the nerve, and then use that to glue back some simple categories together to get a poset (and these simple categories have certain arrows marked as "to-be-inverted"). For example, let's take a look at what the subdivision does to an arrow. It replaces the arrow --->  with a pair of arrows pointing towards each other  ---> <--- . If we do this replacement to all the arrows in our category, then we get a new category where there are no non-trivial compositions - a poset.

Comment: (cont) If we mark all the backwards arrows as weak equivalences, then when we localize we get something where the arrows can be composed as in the original category. So this is one step closer to what we want. However there are two problems. The first is that we haven't taken care of the compositions in the original category. To handle this we need to use the 2-simplicies in the nerve and use their barycentric subdivision. This will be another poset with certain arrows marked (if you localize those arrows it is equivalent to the usual "2-simplex category" 0 --> 1 --> 2.  (cont....)

Comment: Doing that for all the higher simplices too solves the first problem. The second problem is that this doesn't quite work the way we want for basically the same reason that Zhen Lin's suggestion didn't quite work. We can fix it in a way that is morally similar to what Reid Barton suggested, which is to use a slightly bigger model. So you actually need a double subdivision. This double subdivision shows up in Thomason's original work too. Some of the nuance of the Barwick-Kan work is figuring exactly which arrows to localize in the double subdivision.

Comment: @ChrisSchommer-Pries thanks for the explanation.  Ill try to assimilate.  My category knowledge stops pretty much at the surface of 2-categories.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Yes, this is true. It follows form the work of Barwick and Kan on relative categories as a model for $\infty$-categories.

The idea is similar to how Thomason's work shows that every homotopy type can be modeled by a poset (by taking subdivisions of the category of simplicies of the simplicial set).

Specifically in [ArXiv:1011.1691](https://arxiv.org/abs/1011.1691) and [ArXiv:1101.0772](https://arxiv.org/abs/1101.0772) they construct a Quillen equivalence between the Joyal model structure and the model structure of "Relative Categories". This latter is a model structure on the category of small ordinary categories equipped with a collection of "weak equivalences". Importantly they show that the cofibrant objects in the latter are **relative posets** - relative categories whose underlying category is a poset.

This means that every $\infty$-category can be modeled by a relative poset.

If you are just interested in ordinary categories, then you don't even need the Quillen equivalence. View the ordinary category $C$ as a relative category with trivial weak equivalences. Then its cofibrant replacement in the Barwick-Kan model structure will be a relative poset $(P,W)$, and it will satisfy $C \simeq P[W^{-1}]$.

**Added for clarification**

From the comments to the OP is seems that people want to see  a bit more about how this works. In particular how can we get a cofibrant replacement? Is it functorial?

In the first paper Barwick and Kan construct an adjunction which they then show is a Quillen equivalence:

$$K_\xi: ssSet \leftrightarrows RelCat: N_\xi$$

Here $N_\xi$ is a sort of nerve functor. Claim: for any relative category $C$, $K_\xi N_\xi(C) \to C$ is a cofibrant replacement of $C$ (hence a relative poset modeling $C$). This is clearly functorial in $C$ by construction.

*Proof*: $N_\xi(C)$ will automatically be a cofibrant object in bisimplicial sets in the Reedy(=injective) model structure, and so $K_\xi$, being a left Quillen functor, will send it to a cofibrant relative category.

We just need to know that (1) the counit $\epsilon_\xi :K_\xi N_\xi C \to C$ is a weak equivalence in Relative categories.

Weak equivalences in the model category of relative categories are detected by $N_\xi$ (by construction - it is a transferred model structure). Thus (1) will be true if the map $N_\xi\epsilon_\xi: N_\xi K_\xi N_\xi C \to N_\xi C$ is a weak equivalence.

Prop 10.3 in 1011.1691 states that the unit map $\eta_\xi: id \to N_\xi K_\xi$ is always a weak equivalence. Thus $\eta_\xi N_\xi$ is a weak equivalence. This is a left inverse of $N_\xi \epsilon_\xi$, so by two-out-of-three $N_\xi \epsilon_\xi$, and hence $\epsilon_\xi$ are weak equivalences. $\square$

You can also get an easier description using the functor "$N$" rather than the more cumbersome $N_\xi$. See section 7-8 of that same paper.

Comment: This is beautiful, thanks! In the last paragraph, I suppose you're using the following observation: if the $\infty$-categorical localization $P[W^{-1}]$ _happens_ to be a 1-category, then it coincides with the 1-categorical localization (which unfortunately I also denoted $P[W^{-1}]$).

Comment: Yes, that is one way to get that. If you dive into the Barwick-Kan machinery a bit more you can also see that the $\infty$-categorical localization $P[W^{-1}]$ can be taken to mean the hammock localization, whose homotopy category is the usual 1-categorical localization.

Comment: @TimCampion Your advisor was clearly negligent. He should have had you read all of the Barwick-Kan papers. I think I might write him a pointed email instructing him to do better in the future ;) .  (Regardless, I think you would enjoy these papers very much. Most of them are very short and to-the-point -- a rare quality in our field; Also Kan's literary style comes through strongly and is quite singular among math papers - I personally love it, though I know some hate it. Also the n-relative category model is wild! Worth knowing about!!).

Comment: Haha! I think you did encourage me to read those papers a few times, and I think I looked a little bit, but I didn't end up going through in detail.